# What to do if I wish I'd worded the question differently?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently asked [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65605/simplified-character-creation-rules-for-dd-5e) about simplified character creation rules, and it's received a few answers, but I'm wishing that instead I'd omitted the word 'rules' and just asked about simplified (or simplifying) character creation.

I'm not sure if the two questions would actually get different answers, but I feel like the difference is significant. What's more, some of the answers do seem to cover what I *wish* I'd asked, but not what I *actually* asked.

Should I choose the answer that fits the asked question best, and make a new question?
Should I leave it alone and choose the answer that fits my needs best?
Should I take what I need from different answers and self-answer?
Should I do something else entirely?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Edit the question

This does have the effect of potentially turning 'good answers for another question into bad answers for this question', but such is life.  The intent of editing for clarity is important even after an answer has been posted.  Answerers who see the edit should adjust their answer, or delete it.  Those who do not see the edit in the question will have their answers downvoted.  This is the intended purpose of the site.  There are only 4 answers to that question, so it shouldn't be that big of a deal.  It is a good idea, but strictly speaking not required, to leave a comment on the answer, so the answerer is notified of the change.

That said, if the question is DRASTICALLY different, just ask another question.

Comment: I'd go with this choice, but if this change significantly impacts any existing answer, I'd also place a comment on that answer as a courtesy, as suggested in Zachiel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. Ask a new question
2. Edit the previous question to explain why the new one and ask the users whose answer is better suited to the second question to repost it there.
3. Also comment on those answers, pointing out the same thing. "I think your answer is good and I liked it, but please repost it there". They will lose votes, which is sad, but whatever, Those answers didn't really fit the original question in the first place so no loss.
4. (if it is possible, ask for answer relocation by the admins)
5. Leave the old question there anyway, for posterity.